# MySQL отдает только нулевой элемент

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

При запросе к БД из PHP

```
  $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `name_board` FROM `board`");
     $query = mysqli_fetch_array($query); 
     $query_count = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(`name_board`) FROM `board`");
     $query_count = mysqli_fetch_array($query_count);
     for ($i=0; $i < $query_count[0]; $i++) { 
       echo '<div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 20px;"><a  href="boards.php">'.$query[$i].'</a></div>';

     }
```

Отдает только один элемент из базы, хотя я в ручную проверил что их больше, как заставить MySQL отдавать мне все строки, а не только первую

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php **Пример #2 Процедурный стиль** Функцию можете сменить на `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Comment: @Visman Результат тот же  `array(1) { ["name_board"]=> string(11) "Первое имя" }`

Comment: @Kernozz Вы обратили внимание, что в данном вам примере функция fetch вызывается в цикле `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` потому что она за один вызов возвращает только одну строку

Comment: @Mike действительно, спасибо